# How to show below javaScript code without brackets?

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

Code:

```
let myClassFellows=[ ['Noor',1],['Jawaria',2]];
console.log(myClassFellows[0]);
```

[Below is the output I want to show without the square brackets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P38ZN.png)

Comment: Why? That's just the way how your browser logs an array to the console.

Comment: You are right. But I just wanted to remove those square brackets from my output. I tried this myClassFellows[0].join(', ') and got the desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you mean without square brackets? Like 'Noor', 1?
If so, you need to concatenate it into a string with `myClassFellows[0].join(', ')`.

Comment: It's working! I got my desired output. Thank you so much!!

Comment: Can you please answer if I want to show the output of this whole code, let myClassFellows=[ ['Noor',1],['Jawaria',2]];  without square brackets. My Output would be like Noor,1  Jawaria,2. What would be the code to get such output without brackets for all array elements.

Comment: I did it with this code:    console.log(myClassFellows+ '  ');

Comment: Did that answer your question? If so, don't forget to mark this answer as the correct one :)